Does the concept of Index is available for LinkedList in DSA?
Does LinkedList have index to get accessed, as how we have it for array??
If yes, please let me know how the index work in LinkedList concept??
Thanks
I am beginner with LinkedList and wanted to understand the mere concept of LL.

You can easily access an element by index in a linked list, but it won't be very efficient - access the element at index i is O(i), as compared to O(1) for an array. If you regularly need to access elements by index then you should be using an array rather than a linked lis.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes! We can easily access linked list element using index,actually accessing the element at n position in linked list is not that efficient cause of its time complexity
Time Complexity of Access a element at nth position is : O(n)
because in LinkedList we need to tranverse the linked the nth index to get the element.So for directly accessing element ArrayList is preferred, which can access element with Time complexity ofO(1) using index

Here is a java code  for ArrayList for your better understanding
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ArrayLists {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   
     //add elements(appending)

     list.add(1);
     list.add(3);
     list.add(4);
     list.add(5);
     System.out.println(list);

    //to get an element
     int element = list.get(0); // 0 is the index
     System.out.println(element);

     //add element in between
     list.add(1,2); // 1 is the index and 2 is the element to be added
     System.out.println(list);

     //set element
     list.set(0,0);
     System.out.println(list);
 }
}

Here you can see how efficiently we can access element using arraylist but if you want you can do it with liked linked as well here is the code for it
public void addInMiddle(int index, String data) {
       if(index > size || index < 0) {
           System.out.println("Invalid Index value");
           return;
       }
       size++;
       Node newNode = new Node(data);
       if(head == null || index == 0) {
           newNode.next = head;
           head = newNode;
           return;
       }
        Node currNode = head;
       for(int i=1; i<size; i++) {
           if(i == index) {
               Node nextNode = currNode.next;
               currNode.next = newNode;
               newNode.next = nextNode;
               break;
           }
           currNode = currNode.next;
       }
   }

